# Change input number by step on button click

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following code in my `functions.php` file, however the script does not seem to be doing what it is intended to do.

My plus and minus buttons have classes `.plus` and my `.minus` respectively.

PHP / JQuery :

```
/*
    ========================================
    Change qty by step on button click
    ========================================
*/
function kia_add_script_to_footer(){ ?>

    <script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery(document).on('click', '.plus', function(e) { // replace '.quantity' with document (without single quote)

            $input = jQuery(this).siblings('.quantity .qty');

            var val = parseInt($input.val());
            var step = $input.attr('step');

            step = 'undefined' !== typeof(step) ? parseInt(step) : 0.5;

            $input.val( val + step ).change();
        });
        jQuery(document).on('click', '.minus',  // replace '.quantity' with document (without single quote)

            function(e) {

            $input = jQuery(this).siblings('.quantity .qty');

            var val = parseInt($input.val());
            var step = $input.attr('step');

            step = 'undefined' !== typeof(step) ? parseInt(step) : 0.5;

            if (val > 0) {
                $input.val( val - step ).change();
            };
        });

     });

    </script>

<?php };

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'kia_add_script_to_footer' );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Apologies for the bland question. I have erased the generic input arrows for `input.qty` and added two buttons (`.minus` and `.plus`). What is meant to happen, is that on click of either `.minus` or `.plus`, the `input.qty` number should decrease or increase by `var step` amount.

As for the question of whether `.qty` is nested inside of `.quantity`, that would be correct. I was not sure if maybe `.qty` was being used elsewhere, so to confirm my coding was correct, I added the parent element's class.

HTML :

```
<div class="quantity">
        <input class="minus" value="-" type="button">
        <input class="input-text qty text" step="0.5" min="0.5" max="10" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" type="number">
        <input class="plus" value="+" type="button">
        <span>press - or + to add/remove meterage per half meter</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than having us dig/read through the code to take our best guess, can you elaborate on *"the script does not seem to be doing what it is intended to do."*? What's the intention vs what is actually happening? And can you share the corresponding HTML to create a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? And last but not least, there seem to be instructional comments telling you to replace `.quantity` with `document` - have you tried this?

Comment: This is not enough of your code to tell what is needed.  For example: your jQuery selectors inside `jQuery(this).siblings('.quantity .qty');` could be wrong.  Is it supposed to be elements with class `qty` who are INSIDE other elements with class `quantity`?  Because that's what you're selecting here.  If it's trying to be elements with EITHER class, you need a comma between them.  Likewise we don't know what their siblings are.  I suggest making a jsfiddle (try Google if you don't know what that is) and skip the PHP.  You're not really using PHP in your code anyway.

Comment: This looks more like a wordpress question so you should consider asking it at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com There you will also find this [Question/answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33008/how-to-add-a-javascript-snippet-to-the-footer-that-requires-jquery) which might helps. The problem is you need to load `jQuery` before your `javascript` there are many ways to solve that. You need to solve that first. 
 And have a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: @TylerRoper - Please check the EDIT I applied to the original question.

Comment: @Bing - Please check the EDIT I applied to the original question.

Comment: @caramba - jQuery is definitely not the issue, as I have more code that is working correctly. Thank you for your response though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead of [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Note: I've changed

```
step = 'undefined' !== typeof(step) ? parseInt(step) : 0.5;
```

to

```
step = step != null ? parseFloat(step) : 0.5;
```

only in the "plus function" to show another way how you could check the value.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(document).on('click', '.plus', function(e) {

    $input = jQuery(this).siblings('.quantity .qty');

    var val = parseFloat($input.val());
    var step = $input.attr('step');

    step = step != null ? parseFloat(step) : 0.5;

    $input.val( val + step );
});

jQuery(document).on('click', '.minus',  // replace '.quantity' with document (without single quote)

    function(e) {

    $input = jQuery(this).siblings('.quantity .qty');

    var val = parseFloat($input.val());
    var step = $input.attr('step');

    step = 'undefined' !== typeof(step) ? parseFloat(step) : 0.5;

    if (val > 0) {
        $input.val( val - step ).change();
    };
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="quantity">
        <input class="minus" value="-" type="button">
        <input class="input-text qty text" step="0.5" min="0.5" max="10" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" type="number">
        <input class="plus" value="+" type="button">
        <span>press - or + to add/remove meterage per half meter</span>
</div>
```

**And here the same with less code and with always one decimal place** see comments.

```js
var round = function (value, precision) {
    var multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision || 0);
    return Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier;
}

jQuery(document).on('click', '.plus, .minus', function(e) {
    var $input = jQuery(this).siblings('.quantity .qty');

    var val  = parseFloat($input.val());
    var step = parseFloat($input.attr('step'));

    step = step == null ? 0.5 : step;

    var sum = val + step;

    if($(this).hasClass('minus')) {
        sum = val - step;
    }
    
    $input.val(sum.toFixed(1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="quantity">
        <input class="minus" value="-" type="button">
        <input class="input-text qty text" step="0.5" min="0.5" max="10" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" type="number">
        <input class="plus" value="+" type="button">
        <span>press - or + to add/remove meterage per half meter</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You sir, are an absolute legend! I love how you provided a minimalist version also!

Comment: On a side note, how would I go about making a statement that if the value is 1, that it will add ' .0 ' to the end of it. I ask because at the moment it goes `0.5` to `1` and I think it would look nicer still having that decimal value at the end of 1

Comment: @Jesse I've updated the last code snippet with `$input.val(sum.toFixed(1))` which will do the trick. (google is your friend for those kind of questions)

Comment: Wow, something so simple! However it doesnt seem to be working in the snippet or on my website :( I saw that pop up in Google searches but don't know how it would work haha Basic knowledge, but Im learning slowly

Comment: @Jesse ooh you right, kind of :) it's working in Chrome and Safari but it's not in Firefox, which browser are you using? If firefox read this: https://www.zigpress.com/2016/12/05/javascript-tofixed-does-not-work-in-number-fields-on-firefox/

Comment: Ahha! Yes, I noticed it works on my mobile (Chrome) but not on my laptop (Firefox). I have read the link and realize there isn't really a way around this due to the input needing to be a `[type="number"]` for WooCommerce to work :/ Thank you though! A very little problem haha